# using the <include/> in android programming

Tags: java, android, include

I am making an app, and I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="325dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_claim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Claim" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I made a button called View_list that wants to see only the expandable  list view on the entire page.  what I did is create a new XML file, and added the follwing include statement:

```
 <include android:id="@+id/lvExp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

However, I realized that this will now work for two reasons

1 - There is no layout ID

2- I only want the list, not the button and everything else I am going to put in the original layout.  What is going to happen is if I add something to the list, I need to be able to view it without the option of adding antthing to it.

My question is therefore this:

How do I find the layout ID and how can I prevent the entire layout from showing, and only show the list.  I would really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1):

The include should say:

```
 <include layout="@layout/View_list" 
         android:id="@+id/lvExp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This includes the `View_list.xml` layout in another layout.

But I dont really understand why you would use an `include` here if you don't want to re-use the whole layout, but only the list part of it. `include`s exist to easily use layouts in other layouts, if you need just a `ListView`, use just a `ListView`.

EDIT: I'm not sure anymore if I got your question right, but I'll not delete the answer because you commented on it. 
If you want to hide the button or other Views on the click of a button, you can set their visibility to gone programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for the information. how would you suggest I use only the list then?  I understand what you are saying, but I am not sure how to do it otherwise.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the list is a layout file by itself.  Then <include> the list in each place you want it.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes a lot of sense.